# delete in dataTable server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have this issue in my users list, the dataTable server side is working nice, show me all the users I have I put the buttons for view profile, edit profile and delete profile. The ID is in the href and send to the exact user id. The only one error is when I try to delete any user...the ajax I have to delete the user by ID don't do nothing... can you help me, please.

Here is the server side (only the connection):

```
$aColumns = array( 'id_user', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'id_tipo');

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "id_user";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "USERS";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']       = "soft_chas";
$gaSql['password']   = "123456";
$gaSql['db']         = "soft_chas";
$gaSql['server']     = "localhost";
```

The js dataTable:

```
$('#userTabla').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
    "sAjaxSource": "server_processing.php",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "id_user" },
        { "mData": "nombre" },
        { "mData": "apellido" },
        { "mData": "tipo" },
        {
            "mData": null,
            "sClass": "center",
            "sDefaultContent": "",
            "fnRender": function (o) {
            return '<a href="user_profile.php?id_user=' + o.aData[0] + '" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Ver perfil</a> <a href="user_edit.php?id_user=' + o.aData[0] + '" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Editar</a> <a id="' + o.aData[0] + '" class="btn btn-danger" href="#"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i> Borrar</a>'
        },
        "aTargets": [3]
        }
    ],
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ registros por pag"
    }
});
```

JS for delete user by ID:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('table#userTabla td a.btn-danger').click(function(e)
    {
        if (confirm("<?php $translate->__("Do you really want to delete User's record?"); ?>"))
        {
         e.returnValue = false;
         var id = $(this).attr('id');
         var data = 'recordToDelete='+ id;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "include/delete.php",
                   data: data,
                   cache: false,

                   success: function()
                   {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                   }
             });                
        }
    });
    $('table#userTabla tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
});
```

The DELETE code:

```
<?php 
include_once("configs.php");
if(isset($_POST["recordToDelete"]) && strlen($_POST["recordToDelete"])>0 && is_numeric($_POST["recordToDelete"])) {
  $idToDelete = filter_var($_POST["recordToDelete"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if($stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM USERS WHERE id_user = $idToDelete"))
    $stmt->bindParam("$idToDelete", $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
$conn = null;
?>
```

The table in the page:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable" id="userTabla" serverSide="true" processing="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th><?php $translate->__('Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php $translate->__('Last Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php $translate->__('Type'); ?></th>
            <th><?php $translate->__('Actions'); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty center"><i class="icon-refresh"></i><img src="img/ajax-loaders/ajax-loader-1.gif" title="ajax-loaders">&nbsp;<?php $translate->__('Please wait'); ?> ...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: add your php code for delete `include/delete.php`

Comment: @VolkanUlukut, I already added the code

Comment: @VolkanUlukut, thank you for your support but the ajax I thing is the part that not working...because when I hit the delete button there is nothing to show me... even the pop up with "Do you really want to delete User's record?" no show me nothing so the ajax is like don't see the button or the id... but I see in the code the id of each user..

Comment: do you see any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: not shown me any errors the console and if I use this ajax in another type of dataTable without the server side is working normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this ajax js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).delegate('.btn-danger', 'click', function() { 
        if (confirm("<?php $translate->__("Do you really want to delete User's record?"); ?>"))
        {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var data = 'recordToDelete='+ id;
            var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "include/delete.php",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function()
                {
                    parent.fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                }
            });                
        }
    });
    $('table#userTabla tr:odd').css('background',' #FFFFFF');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your bindParam statement got some issues. check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php). $id_user is not defined and you are not using named parameter in your bindParam. try this:

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM USERS WHERE id_user = ?"))
$stmt->bindParam(1, $idToDelete, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```